# mySql update with the sum() of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
    "id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
    "1"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "100"       "0"
    "2"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "50"        "0"
    "3"     "100"   "0"         "US"        "150"       "0" ->150 = sum(votes) where type = 1 and country = country
    "4"     "1"     "0"         "SE"        "50"        "0"
    "5"     "1"     "0"         "SE"        "25"        "0"
    "6"     "100"   "0"         "SE"        "75"        "0" ->75 = sum(votes) where type = 1 and country = country
```

I'm trying to update `type=100` with the totals of all `type=1` for their respective countries.

I've been struggling with this sql and seem to going nowhere. Basically, what I'm trying to do is update votes where type=100 with the sum of type = 1 for their respective countries.
I've been trying to tweak this, but seem to be failing completely. Can you pls help?

```
UPDATE likes p
JOIN likes h
  ON p.country = h.country
    AND (p.type=1) AND h.type=1
SET p.votes=sum(h.votes) where p.type=100;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  country, SUM(votes) totalVotes
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   type = 1
            GROUP   BY country
        ) b ON a.country = b.country
SET     a.votes = b.totalVotes
WHERE   a.type = 100
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0785c/1)